# Why is this usage of MySQL's "USING" clause incorrect?

Tags: mysql, using

In MySQL v5.7 using the InnoDB engine, I have a table called `birds` and another one called `conservation_status`, which look like the following:

```
mysql> describe birds;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| bird_id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| scientific_name        | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| common_name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| family_id              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| conservation_status_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| wing_id                | char(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body_id                | char(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bill_id                | char(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description            | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
mysql> describe conservation_status;
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| conservation_status_id | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| conservation_category  | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| conservation_state     | char(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm experimenting with the `USING` clause, and I'm trying to join the two tables on the `conservation_status_id` column with such a clause, but I get an error related to my use of the column name:

```
select * from birds join conservation_status USING conservation_status_id;
```

I know the use case of `USING` is for when the column used to join two tables has the same name in each table, therefore the problem can't be an ambiguous column name match.

I've verified in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) that my version of MySQL supports this clause, and I've verified that there are no typos in the column name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `USING` must be in parentheses. It's not just a column identifier, it's a *tuple*.

```
select * from birds join conservation_status USING (conservation_status_id);
```

It needs to be a tuple because you can join on multiple columns, for example:

```
select * from table1 join table2 USING (col1, col2, col3)
```